# Fetch Request Causing Page reload

Tags: javascript, html

My page keeps on reloading after my fetch request is complete. I don't want the page to reload after I submit the form. Can anyone help out as to why even after using e.preventDefault() I get that behavior? Also can you suggest better formatting tips for JS as I'm a beginner and would like your input. I'm fetching the data from a fake REST API made using json-live-server

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="body">
  <h1> Vaccination Centers</h1>
  <div id='app'>
    <form id='form'>
      <input type="text" id='enrollment' />
      <input type='text' id='session' />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    let listArray

function getCenters () {
  fetch ('http://localhost:3001/students')
    .then(
      response => response.json()
    )
    .then(data => {
      listArray = data
      console.log(listArray)
    })
};

function init () {
  getCenters()
  const form = document.getElementById('form')
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => validate(e))
}

function validate (e) {
  console.log(e)
  e.preventDefault()
  let enrollment = document.getElementById('enrollment').value
  let student = listArray.find(s => s.enrollment.toString() === enrollment.toString())
  fetch ('http://localhost:3001/students/' + student.id, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' // Indicates the content
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ paidFee: true })
  }).then(document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = 'HELLO BITCHES')
}

window.onload = init
```

Comment: Place a preventDefault on your forms submit event.

Comment: @Keith I tried that, form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    return validate()
  })         still page keeps on reloading :/

Comment: return false from validate

Comment: Just use `form.addEventListener('submit', validate)`. Don't try and get fancy with arrow functions when there's no need.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. (My best guess is that there is a fault loading the script which would give you an obvious CORS error in the browser's developer tools Console)

Answer (score 1):

We can all agree that `e.preventDefault()` placed at the first line  ⃰  in the event handler (aka `validate(e)`) will [stop the default browser behavior](https://javascript.info/default-browser-action) of a `<form>` when a `"submit"` event is triggered on it. The behavior OP is observing is the destructive overwriting of the following:

```
.then(document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = 'HELLO BITCHES')
```

Just remove the above and you shouldn't have what appears as a page reload, but if you must say, *"HELLO"* to the bitches, use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead:

```
.then(document.getElementBYId('app').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', 'HELLO BITCHES'))
```

The following example has an event handler for the `"submit"` (`submitter(e)`) and `"click"` (`clicker(e)`) events. If `button#A` is clicked, `.innerHTML` is used and if `button#B` is clicked, `.insertAdjacentHTML()` is used. There is also a logger function (`eventLogger(e)`) which will log:

- type of event........................................`e.type`
- event listener `#id`............................`e.currentTarget`
- button `#id`..........................................`e.target.id` (from `'click'` event)
- if default was prevented or not.....`e.defaultPrevented`

⃰actually it's `console.log()` at that position but there's no difference in this context

***Best viewed in Full Page mode***

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', submitter);
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(node => node.addEventListener('click', clicker));

function submitter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let ID = this.elements.AB.value;
  const APP = document.getElementById('app');

  switch (ID) {
    case 'A':
      APP.innerHTML = 'HELLO BITCHES - #app is gutted by .innerHTML - everything within #app is overwritten';
      break;
    case 'B':
      const htmlString = 'HELLO BITCHES - this is added in front of #app - nothing is overwritten bitches';
      APP.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', htmlString);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  eventLogger(e);
};

function clicker(e) {
  document.forms[0].AB.value = e.target.id;
};

function eventLogger(e) {
  let ID = e.target.elements.AB.value;
  console.clear()
  let log = 'Event Type: ' + e.type + '\nEvent Listener ID: ' + e.currentTarget.id + '\nButton ID: ' + ID + '\nDefault Prevented: ' + e.defaultPrevented;
  console.log(log);
};
```

```css
body {
  padding: 8px;
  font: 1ch/1 Consolas;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.75ch/1;
}

#app {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 3px dashed blue;
}

form {
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 3px dotted red
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15ch;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6ch;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

p:first-of-type {
  color: blue;
}

p:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}

code {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ab00ef;
}


/* SO Console Display - Right Side Column */

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 50% !important;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 25% 50%;
  font-size: 0.8ch/1;
  font-variant: normal;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <h1>Vaccination Centers</h1>
  <p>Blue dashed outline is <code>#app</code></p>
  <p>Red dotted outline is <code>#form</code></p><br>
  <div id='app'>
    <form id='form'>
      <input type="text" id='enrollment'>
      <input type='text' id='session'>
      <button id='A'>A</button>
      <button id='B'>B</button>
      <input id='AB' type='hidden'>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

There were a few bits that needed some attendence:

In your original script you used an asynchronous fetch to define the variable `listArray`. Unfortunately you did not wait for the value to be put into that variable but continued straight away. This "awaiting" can only happen in an asynchronous function. Therefore:

- I created an `async` function as this makes it much easier to process promises with `await` inside.
- The first one fills `listArray` with all the registered students for comparison with an entered name
- The comparison needs to be done on `enrollment.value.trim().toLowerCase()`  (there is no `.toString()` involved)
- If the name was found, a second `fetch()` command is sent, "PATCHing" the new information to the server
- The return data from the server is then displayed in JSON format under the "success message".

```js
const api='http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/';
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit",validate);

async function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const listArray=await fetch(api).then(r=>r.json());
  let student= listArray.find(s=>s.username.toLowerCase()===enrollment.value.trim().toLowerCase())
  if (student) {
   const d = await fetch(api+student.id, {method: 'PATCH',headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},body: JSON.stringify({paidFee:true})}).then(r=>r.json());
   document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = '<div>HELLO BITCHES</div><pre>'+JSON.stringify(d,null,2)+'</pre>';
  } else console.log("This student does not exist in our list: "+listArray.map(s=>s.username).join(" "));
}
```

```html
<h1> Vaccination Centers</h1>
<div id='app'>
  <form id='form'>
     <input type="text" id='enrollment' value="Bret">
     <input type='text' id='session'>
     <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```